# EXEC PID for perl files

Tags: perl, process, exec, pid

I have a Perl file which has an exec command in it. I was wondering if there is someway I can find the P.I.D  of that process??? Then the exec command has another exec command in it. So is there a way I can get the P.I.D of the latest exec (in depth) being executed at the moment? I am using Perl, I don't know much about other languages, so if you think it will work, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

As pavel said the `PID` stays the same after the `exec`, since this basically replaced the currently running process with the new one (and after the `exec` the calling process is NOT continued!). That said, you can always get *your* PID by looking at `$$`, e.g.

```
my $pid = $$;
print "My pid is $pid\n";
```

If you create a new child process (`fork`), then you get the PID of that process as the return value of the `fork()` call (in the parent process).

Hope this helps you,
 Christian

Answer (score 1):

`exec` replaces the current progam with the one executed. So the PID remains the same...