# How to get the PID of a program executed within a Perl script

Tags: perl, pid

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18094448/exec-pid-for-perl-files) explains how to get the pid of the new process when using Perl's `exec()`. The pid doesn't even change, so all you need to do is get the pid of the original script. But it doesn't work if I redirect the output to a file as part of the command, which I need to do.

```
say "my pid is $$";
exec("childscript.pl");                  # same pid
```

But if I redirect the output as part of the command:

```
say "my pid is $$";
exec("childscript.pl > log.txt");        # different pid, usually old pid + 1
exec("childscript.pl > log.txt 2>&1 &"); # same
```

then the new pid is one higher than the old one (which is probably just because they were spawned in succession and not reliable). I tested this both by looking at the output, and by inserting a `sleep 30` into "childscript.pl" so that I could see it with `ps -e`.

My guess here is that redirecting the output causes a new process to do the writing. But I need the pid of the program, and I have no control over the program except for the fact that I can execute it. (It needs to run in the background too.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `exec` with a single argument (and that argument contains shell metacharacters), perl automatically runs `sh -c ARG` for you. In your case:

```
exec("childscript.pl > log.txt");
# really means:
exec("/bin/sh", "-c", "childscript.pl > log.txt");
```

I.e. your script loads `sh` into the currently running process, keeping its PID. The shell performs output redirection, then runs `childscript.pl` as a child process (with a new PID).

There are two ways to attack this problem:

1. Do the output redirection in Perl and don't spawn a shell:

   ```
   open STDOUT, ">", "log.txt" or die "$0: log.txt: $!\n";
   exec "childscript.pl";
   die "$0: childscript.pl: $!\n";
   ```
2. Tell the shell to also use `exec` and not spawn a child process:

   ```
   exec "exec childscript.pl > log.txt";
   die "$0: childscript.pl: $!\n";
   ```

Comment: Excellent! Both methods work. Is there any one that's preferable for whatever reason? I suppose the second method relies on the shell having a compatible implementation of `exec`, but I would guess it's the same across *NIXes and like it because it's one line.

Comment: @felwithe, Involving the shell invokes a lot more work and a lot more things that can go wrong. Always opt for the option that removes unnecessary pieces.